# Need Basic Visual Studio 2010 Help

Tags: vb.net

So I have a code atm that has 2 combo boxes, one to select the make, then it will enable the model, I have 3 model choices, here's code:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmb_make_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cmb_make.Items.Add("Toyota")
        cmb_make.Items.Add("Nissan")
        cmb_make.Items.Add("Hyundai")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_finish.Click
        If cmb_make.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please select your make")
        End If

        If cmb_model.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please select your model")
        End If

        If cmb_model.Text = ("Supra") Then
            Form3.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If

        If cmb_model.Text = ("MR2") Then
            Form4.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If

        If cmb_model.Text = ("Hilux") Then
            Form5.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If

        If cmb_model.Text = ("R34") Then
            Form6.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If

        If cmb_model.Text = ("R33") Then
            Form7.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If

        If cmb_model.Text = ("R32") Then
            Form8.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If

        If cmb_model.Text = ("Genesis Coupe") Then
            Form9.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If

        If cmb_model.Text = ("RD1 Coupe") Then
            Form10.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If

        If cmb_model.Text = ("Excel") Then
            Form11.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub EditToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles EditToolStripMenuItem.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmb_make_SelectedIndexChanged_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmb_make.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim Strchoice As String

        Strchoice = cmb_make.SelectedItem
        If Strchoice = "Toyota" Then

        End If
        cmb_model.Items.Clear()
        cmb_model.Items.Add("Supra")
        cmb_model.Items.Add("MR2")
        cmb_model.Items.Add("Hilux")


        If Strchoice = "Nissan" Then
            cmb_model.Items.Clear()
            cmb_model.Items.Add("R34")
            cmb_model.Items.Add("R32")
            cmb_model.Items.Add("R33")

        ElseIf Strchoice = "Hyundai" Then
            cmb_model.Items.Clear()
            cmb_model.Items.Add("RD1 Coupe")
            cmb_model.Items.Add("Genesis Coupe")
            cmb_model.Items.Add("Excel")
```

Once I have selected my model of the car, it takes me to that specific form with a picture of that model, I then want to display individual parts, with individual prices that will add up in a text box above, can someone help me and tell me how? Please this is due tomorrow I'm freaking out!!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the parts into picture boxes on the model's form and have either check boxes or radio buttons (depending on what functionality you are required to do) underneath that have the prices as labels and then use an if structure to assign a value to them that can be totaled in the text box.

```
Dim total as double

If chk_part1.checked = true then
   total += partPrice

If chk_part2.checked = true then
   total += partPrice

txtTotal.text = total
```

Not saying that this code is perfect but you could implement something along those lines to get the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a For Each Statement.  Such as:

```
Dim Form As New Form3.ControlCollection(Me)

    For Each CheckBox As CheckBox In Form
        If CheckBox.Checked = True Then
              total  += partPrice
        End If
    Next
```

So, In essense, it should cycle through all of the check boxes and, if they are checked, it adds the part price to the total.